# Ruby on Rails - get checkbox parameter and change value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

*I would like to get the parameter from a checkbox and modify the values.
So if the checkbox is checked the value should be in the model 1, otherwise 0.*

Every time when i check the model it say's to me:

```
#<User id: 1, name: "admin", email: "admin@bl.ch", created_at: "2013-11-04 07:18:34", updated_at: "2013-11-04 07:18:34", password_digest: "$2a$10$Gk7IF2OE1GxxeZdqFXygMezwNrurv.6yemuOFSNjLKFS...", role: nil>
```

It should be `role: 1` or `role: 0`

controller

```
def create

role = User.new(params[:role]) #get params

 # if role.exists?
 if role == 0 
  role = 0
 else
  role = 1
 end
end
```

html

```
<% provide(:title, 'Log In') %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email, 'E-Mail' %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password, 'Passwort' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Passowrt wiederholen" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.label :role, 'Ist Admin?'%>
      <%= f.check_box :role %><br><br>

      <%= f.submit "Account erstellen", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when u r cheking the check box then print the params in controller for checkbox and update .

Answer (score 0):

Since `role` is a new `User` object, you don't want to test `role == 0`.

If you want to set the role based on the parameter being passed, use `if params[:role]`. To modify the role of the `User` object, use `role.role=`.

It would be less confusing if you named the object `user` or `new_user` since `role` is just an attribute of `User`.

```
if params[:role]
  role.role = 0
else
  role.role = 1
end
```

Comment: hmmm... I don't know what you mean.. can you make me an example?

Comment: @ciaodarwin updated the example but please don't use this as the solution. Rename `role`

Answer (score 0):

Hi though i am not sure but it seems that you are not using the strong parameters the way you must have it seems that you have not added :role in your permitted parameters list and thats why you are bearing all this pain of manually testing for value of params[:role]. Better add :role in your permitted parameters list.
Read in this link:- http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Yes but also read below comment by Musannif. Becaue you are using model object in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with User object and role. Since you are creating a user object by new method, the attributes must be accessed by using dot method.

```
user = User.new(params[:role])
```

This gives an user object. Now you can access all other attributes as getter methods.

```
if user.role == 0
   #do something
else
   #do something
end
```

At last you can do a *user.save* to save all the model values. By this, the next time you can access the role attribute.